# How to Remove [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (1 values for 6 columns)

Tags: java, database, sqlite

```
  String nam = name.getText();
    String bloodgrp = bgroup.getText();
    String addre = address.getText();
    String phn = phone.getText();
    String ref = refrence.getText();
    String will = willing.getText();

    String query ="insert into Blooddoner(Name,Bgroup,Address,Phone,Refrence,Willing) "
            + "values('"+nam+"''"+bloodgrp+"''"+addre+"''"+phn+"''"+ref+"''"+will+"')";
```

In this code i am getting error . And i am not able to understand the meaning of this error

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (1
>   values for 6 columns)

Comment: You missed comma in values . Comma for separating column values

Comment: Yet another reason to use statements.

Answer (score 1):

you are inserting in wrong manner values must be comma separated, give comma in between your values.